# Animate div based on position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've done the following to animate divs to get a sort of zooming effect.

**HTML**

```
<div class='tile-container'>
    <div class='tile'>
        <p>testing</p>
    </div>
    <div class='tile'></div>
    <div class='tile'></div>
    <div class='tile'></div>
    <div class='tile'></div>
    <div class='tile'></div>
    <div class='clearfix'></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.tile').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('clicked')){
        return false;
    }

    var itemPosition = $(this).position(),
        containerWidth = ( $('.tile-container').width() / 100 ) * 91,
        containerHeight = ( $('.tile-container').height() / 100 ) * 86,
        clone = $(this).clone();

    $(clone).css({
        'position':'absolute',
        'top': -itemPosition.top,
        'left': itemPosition.left
    }).appendTo('.tile-container').animate({
        width : containerWidth,
        height: containerHeight
    }).children().fadeOut("slow").promise().done(function(){
        $(clone).append("<p class='back'>back</p>").addClass('clicked')
    });
})

$(document).on('click','.back',function(){
    var tile = $(this).parent()
    $(tile).animate({
        width : '50px',
        height: '50px'
    },function(){
        $(tile).remove();
    })
})
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.tile-container{
    background-color:#ccc;
    width:210px;
    height:140px;
}
.tile{
    background-color:blue;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    margin:10px;
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.clearfix{
    clear:both;
}
```

[The working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z1xwxan5/7/)

The animation works fine for first left element. How can I manage the rest of the elements with various positions.

Comment: check these [Grid Style](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/9bzu33r2/) or [Sliding Divs](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/66eq9em2/) for reference. Hope they help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add top:0 and left:0 style to the animate

```
.appendTo('.tile-container').animate({
        width : containerWidth,
        height: containerHeight,
        'top': 0,
        'left': 0
    })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z1xwxan5/13/

Answer (score 1):

You need to animate the `top`, `left` property for those divs on the `on.click` event.

Closest I could get is: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z1xwxan5/14/).

Comment: The animation should appear as it starts form the element it self!

Comment: That actually slides to the first position and then animates! the core animation should stat from the position of the clicked element. Which mean, the element should not animate it self to `top`:`0` and `left`:`0` but be at the clicked place and then the enlarging animation should fire

Comment: Yes, but you need to move the div to that position in order for it to not get out of the outer container. You just have to make it look smooth.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93356/discussion-between-florin-pop-and-dimal-chandrasiri).

Answer (score 0):

If you add top:0 and left:0 to the animate it'll come from the element you want.

```
animate({
    top : 0,
    left : 0,
    width : containerWidth,
    height: containerHeight
})
```

To make it go back is a little trickier, but I guess just make itemPosition a global scope variable that gets assigned when you click an element, and then use that to animate top:itemPosition.top and left:itemPosition.left.

Fiddle: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z1xwxan5/12/)